# Events in a chess clock c#

Tags: c#, events

I am building af chess clock in c#. In this clock I increment with seconds for each draw. The draw comes from hitting a button. The seconds in the incrementing is chosen in a combobox 'comboboxSeconds'. I want to use this value 5, 10, 15 seconds in the button event method. How do I subscribe to the combobox event so I can use the value in the button click event.

The code is simple:

````
```
  
    private void btnStartHvid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Hvidantal > 1)//we do not increment in the first draw)
        {         
            timeHvid += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);// Add five seconds. Must come from combobox. So it could be 5, 10 or 15
          
        }
       
        lblHvidAntal.Content = Hvidantal++.ToString(); //show number of draws in a label
        DPtimerHvid.Stop();
        DPtimerSort.Start();
       
       
      }            

    private void comboboxSeconds_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)(sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem; //ok
      
        String seconds = cbi.Content.ToString(); //seconds chosen 5, 10 eller 15
      
        
    }
````

Comment: *How do I subscribe to the combobox event* - I wouldn't; instead I'd just retrieve the selected value in the combo, in the code of the button click event. Is it suppsoed to be that the combo can be changed while the timer is running? Or should the combo only be changeable when the clock is stopped, and when running the combo is disabled?

Comment: Please specify the tag for the specific UI framework you are using.

Comment: It could be fancy to change seconds during the game. But standard is that you set the seconds before you start the game og it is the same during the game. So that is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem here is read the selected time from the combobox in the button-handler, so it can be used to increment the time.

Assuming wpf, you should be able to use the [SelectionBoxItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.selectionboxitem?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property to check the selected time. I.e.

```
timeHvid += TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)myCombobox.SelectedItem);
```

You might want to assign a name to your combobox, i.e. insert `x:Name="myCombobox"` in the xaml.

Also, you need to decide what type of objects you want to put into your combobox. Using strings will make it more difficult to convert the value to a time. Using int will work fine if you only want to show the numbers, and no additional text. Or you could use a custom class to store both the actual value, and override `ToString` to determine how the value should be displayed.